# Ruby on Rails Dynamically generate field name in view using variable from view helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, view-helpers

In my view, let's say I have something like this:

```
<%= f.text_field :name_first %>
```

and another time this:

```
<%= f.text_field :name_last %>
```

Instead of hard-coding the field names, I want to dynamically generate them using a view helper method.

```
def category_name
    @contact_info.category.name
end

def return_field_name
  category_lower = category_name.downcase
  ":name"+category_lower  
end
```

So now my view should have something like this:

```
 <%= f.text_field return_field_name %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write:

```
def return_field_name
  category_lower = category_name.downcase
  "name#{category_lower}".to_sym
  # but I'm sure that without #to_sym it should work as well
end
```

But if it will help you you should write only pure methods. IMHO it's very good practice.

Comment: Thank you!  This is exactly what I needed.  Works like a charm.  I can't accept the answer as I only have 11 rep points (4 short).  As soon as I can, I will return here to accept.  Thanks again!